# passing parameters to partial helper from different modules

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an issue with using partial helper in view. My partial is in Application module.
When I try to use it in different modules in my app. I cannot access parameters of my partial from inside partial.

partial('partial/alert', 'Application', array('hello'=>'greeting'));?>
so $hello appears to be undefined

but when I call partial from Application module:
partial('partial/alert', array('hello'=>'greeting'));?>
I can access $hello
Please help me!

Comment: Unlike ZF1, in ZF2 it doesn't matter what module the partial is in - the syntax for rendering it is the same. So always provide 2 parameters (not 3), as per Sam's answer. If this isn't working, we'll need to see the actual code you're using, and how your testing whether or not the variables are set from within the partial.

Comment: Thank you! It is clear now. 
So docs are incorrect I think. It says partial should be passed three params:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what your problem is. You have the solution already so why even ask? ViewHelpers are globally, you can not restrict them to a single module.

See [the ViewHelper::partial Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html)

In short, stick to `$this->partial('partial/alert', array('hello'=>'greeting'));`

Comment: my problem is: I cannot pass any variables to partial when I don't use it in Application module. I need to use it in other modules of my app and pass parameters to it, but I canot.

Comment: @KonstantinVahrushev that's not possible. The partial view helper is global and not tied to a specific module. Show us EXACTLY what you're doing in what file.

Comment: Sam, thank you for pointing that they are global. Because after reading the documentation
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html
Rendering Partials in Other Modules

I thought partial is ristricted to a single module.

Comment: @KonstantinVahrushev well yes THESE docs are incorrect. However those are the docs for 2.1. We're at 2.3 already ;) Always access the latest docs available if possible. Many docs of 2.0 and 2.1 still contain many fragments of the documentation from ZF 1.x